# What's a shebang line for Scala that doesn't corrupt mimetype?

Tags: scala, shebang

I've been using this, but it changes the mimetype to `text/x-shellscript`, which makes editors like Emacs treat my code like Shell scripts.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
```

Comment: I reading the book Programming in Scala by Martin Odersky and he listed  this `...exec...` as the solution  in AppendixA to run a scala script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The bangshe (!#) might be the problem**

*I commented out the !# and the following works in my environment:*

File: hello.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala

val name = readLine("What is your name? ")
println("Hello " + name + "!")
```

Changed to executable permissions and then ran:

```
chmod a+x hello.scala
./hello.scala
```

Comment: Next step: Drop the `.sh` from the file name! The whole point of the shebang line is to make scripts indistinguishable (to a first approximation) to the end user. Besides, it's not really a Shell script, is it?

Comment: Right you are.  Just to be clear: if the file was named hello.scala it shouldn't have the shebang.  If it has the shebang it can be run like a script -- no "main" necessary.

Comment: Excellent! Works for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

As I can test, just

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala
!#

println("Args: " + args.toList)
```

works fine:

```
➜ ./test.scala 1 hi
Args: List(1, hi)
```

Or you may write it without `/usr/bin/env`, for fixed `scala` path

Comment: So does `#!/usr/bin/env scala`! But sadly the compiler `scalac` doesn't accept shebangs.

Comment: Just `#!/usr/bin/env scala` don't work for me:

`error: script file does not close its header with !# or ::!#`

Have no idea, how to achieve shebang and scalac support simulteniously, `#` is not comment in Scala

Comment: Which version of Scala are you using? Mine is 2.10.0

Comment: Version 2.10 and 2.11 are working for me with `#!/usr/bin/env scala` as the sehbang line.