# How to use a specific file name in a scala exec bash file?

Tags: bash, scala

How would I write the following bash script replacing the actual code of the scala section (after the !#) line to be called from a .scala file and then call its main method?

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world! " + args.toList)
  }
}
HelloWorld.main(args)
```

keep in mind i do not have access to scalac

Comment: Maybe this is what you're actually trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077341/whats-a-shebang-line-for-scala-that-doesnt-corrupt-mimetype

Comment: @Kenster not quite! but this is helpful for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean dividing the file into two parts...

*file.scala*

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world! " + args.toList)
  }
}
HelloWorld.main(args)
```

*launch.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "file.scala" "$@"
```

Comment: YES! this is exactly what I was looking for! 
out of curiosity what does the "$@" stand for?

Comment: @Zee: [Source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html) `$@` is bash internal/special variable which is expanded to all the parameters received (in this particular case by `launch.sh`). That means if you call `./launch.sh arg1 arg2`, then `"$@"` will be expanded to `arg1 arg2`