# Shebang "#!" starts and "!#" ends?

Tags: bash, scala, shell, shebang

I have been using shebang `#!` for a while and today came across a use case that confuses me.

There are several ways to run scala script like

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala 
println("hello world")
```

However, I came across this version of shebang

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
println("hello world")
```

Looks like this solution basically invokes the bash first, the run `exec scala "$0" "$@"` where `$0` denotes the current file name and `$@` is input arguments in a positional array.

My question is does that mean everything between `#!` and `!#` could be executed in bash,

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
echo "oh Yeah"
!#
println("hello world")
```

It did not error out but neither gave me the "oh Yeah" in the stdout, can anyone explain to me what is going on here?

---

update: after realizing `!#` is a scala thing, I downloaded the source code of scala and realized it only appears in the comment of [ScriptRunner.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ScriptRunner.scala) part written by Lex Spoon.

Comment: `exec` replaces the current process with the new process. Nothing after it runs.

Comment: @EtanReisner, then how does the new interpreter (scala interpreter) in this case knows it should start from `println()` and not `echo`, is that where `!#` is  used for?

Comment: In other words, you might be able to get the `echo` to appear if placed before the `exec`.  Perl documents some related notations in [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Answer (score 9):

The `!#` line has no meaning *to the shell*.

The `#!/bin/sh` line means that the script is executed by `/bin/sh`. The `exec scala "$0" "$@"` line invokes `scala`, passing the name of the script and its arguments to the `scala` command. Since `exec` doesn't return, the shell doesn't see the rest of the script.

I don't know Scala, but my educated guess is that the Scala interpreter itself treats everything from the `#!` line to the `!#` line as a comment. It then starts executing with the Scala statement `println("hello world")`.

In short the `!#` is Scala syntax, not shell syntax (but the Scala syntax is designed to let it be used like this in a shell script).

In a quick look at the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/), I haven't found out how this is defined. It's mentioned, but not explained, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15077341/827263). It's likely, as chepner 3's comment suggests, that it's a hack in the Scala interpreter rather than part of the actual language syntax.

som-snytt found the code in the Scala interpreter that implements this [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/util/SourceFile.scala#L71):

```
object ScriptSourceFile {
  /** Length of the script header from the given content, if there is one.
   *  The header begins with "#!" or "::#!" and ends with a line starting
   *  with "!#" or "::!#".
   */
...
```

But I wonder whether it's documented.

Comment: Seems to be a hack in the interpreter itself, since the shebang itself isn't a comment in Scala.

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/util/SourceFile.scala#L71

Comment: @som-snytt: Do you happen to know whether it's documented?